# How to add subview to current navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a project setup that has a uiscrollview that appends 2 view controllers which have table views to allow horizontal scrolling. This is embedded in a navigation controller.

Think of it like this. VC1 is the summary with a button which takes the user to VC2. VC2 is a list of items but there are 2 lists contained in a horizontal scroll view. VC2's lists are VC2.1 and VC2.2. These are view controllers with table views embedded. VC3 is the details view which is accessible after clicking of VC2.1 or VC2.2's cells. VC1 and VC2 both have navigation controllers. VC2.1, VC2.2 and VC3 do not.

I am trying to setup the table view cell to push to a details view. I was able to do this modally using:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc: MyDetailsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myDetailsVC") as! MyDetailsViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However a couple of things are not working like I hope.

1. The view is presented with a navigation bar but no back button
2. The view is presented modally

Is there a way to have this details view be part of the main navigation controller and have it presented sliding in from right to left like all other navigation views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By maintaining the `ViewController` containment you can simply access the `parentViewController`'s `NavigationController`.

While adding `ViewController`'s `view` using `addSubview:` add the `ViewController` to the `ParentViewController` using `addChildViewController:`

```
self.addChildViewController(VC2)

VC2.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
self.view .addSubview(VC2.view)
```